# Multiple field report, with custom counts in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a system I didn't create. The system has 3 main tables:

users, courses, and usergroups. I am using an extra table called coursehits.

It's a MySQL DB, 5.0. There aren't any relationships in the DB, so users are assigned to courses by simply adding an entry to usergroups (course_id and user_id) from the courses and users table. Likewise if they start a course an entry is made to coursehits.

I am trying to count the number of users in coursehits and usergroups for reporting data. So far I have the following which doesn't count correctly in one query but this doesn't count correctly, the results are much too high:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
c.course_name,
COUNT(ug.user_id) AS "Enrolled",
COUNT(ch.user_id) as "Started"

FROM courses c, usergroups ug, coursehits ch, users u

WHERE ch.user_id = u.id
AND ug.user_id = u.id
AND ug.course_id = c.id
AND ch.page_id != 4
GROUP BY 1
```

Before I was doing the following individually which does work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.course_name, COUNT(ug.user_id) AS "Enrolled"
FROM courses c, usergroups ug
WHERE ug.course_id = c.id
GROUP BY 1
```

Where as now I am trying to report the status of users for each course on one query, I hope that makes sense?!?

Comment: Is there any particular purpose why it has to be one query? In SQL, it's better to have two queries doing separate things, than to try to combine it in some weird way.

Comment: Doing it for a developer, I have made the two queries seperately and they work fine, now doing a third. Just convenience I think, as well as pushing my SQL boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.course_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ug.user_id) AS "Enrolled",
       COUNT(DISTINCT ch.user_id) as "Started"
FROM courses c
left join usergroups ug on ug.course_id = c.id
left join coursehits ch on ch.course_id = c.id and ch.page_id != 4
GROUP BY c.course_name
```

Comment: That did it thank you so much, I wish I could give you a point, but I am not cool enough yet :( Thanks again

Comment: @teatime, if you are happy that the answer solves your problem, you should be able to accept it (by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer).